# How lxc-console implements implementation of the process into container?

Tags: linux, process, lxc

Let's assume that we have some host with containers on it. When I type `lxc-console` I can get access from host's `cmd` to container's `cmd`, so I want to know what exactly happens? I mean how `lxc-console` implement process into container and get access to terminal?

Comment: What is the problem you are attempting to solve?  Where have you looked for the answers to this question?  The source and man page for this command is readily available.  (hint search github for LXC)

Comment: @RikSchneider I've already trying to find out answer in LXC source, ty